# using MatchAll in elasticsearch and elastica

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica, foselasticabundle

I am having a hard time trying to use MatchAll in elastic search using elastica, currently I have the following querystring:

```
$pictureQuery = new \Elastica\Query\QueryString();
        $pictureQuery->setParam('query', $searchquery);
        $pictureQuery->setParam('fields', array(
            'caption'
        ));

        $items = $itemFinder->find($pictureQuery);
```

the issue with this query is that it only returns 10 results. I wanted to return all results, in this case MatchAll. I am however having issues on how to get all matching results, how do I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch returns by default the top 10 results (the more relevant).
That's the expected behavior.

Elasticsearch allows to change page size (size) and change page (from). Have a look at [From/Size API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html).

In Elastica, I guess it's here: http://elastica.io/api/classes/Elastica.Query.html#method_setSize

Comment: It's not useful for pagination , how can set that to unlimitted size ?

Comment: It is! If you want to get all results on client side (let say export 10 000 000 of results), use scan and scroll API